# getting "null" while trying to get the value of textbox that is inside a jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the value of a textbox that I have created inside a jquery dialog using its ID and I am receiving null. I think it is some simple mistake, but I am not able to find it. Could you please have a look at the below code and tell me if I am doing anything wrong there.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var name = $("#ip"), email = $("#stnid"), allFields = $(
            []).add(name).add(email);
    $("#displayOrderDetailsDiv").on('click','.shippedOrder',function() {

        var shipmentKey = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
        $( "#printLabelDialog" ).dialog( {
            autoOpen: false,
            height : "auto",
            width : "auto",
            modal: true,
            buttons: [ { 
                text: "Print", 
                click: function() { 
                    var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='loading.gif' alt='loading...' style='width: 20px; height: 20px; top: 50%; left: 50%; position:absolute;' />";
                    $( this ).html(ajax_load);

                    var ip = $("#ipAddr").val();
                    var stnid = $("#stnid").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url : 'printLabelTrackingNumber.jsp',
                        type : 'POST',
                        data : {
                            ipAddr : ip,
                            stationId : stnid
                        },
                        success : function(data) {

                            $("#printLabelDialog").html(data);

                        },
                        error : function(err) {
                            alert(err.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                } 
            } ]
        });
        $("#printLabelDialog").html("<form><fieldset><label for=\"ip\">Printer IP</label> <input type=\"text\" name=\"ip\" id=\"ipAddr\" class=\"text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all\"> <labelfor=\"stnid\">Station ID:</label> <input type=\"text\" name=\"stnid\" id=\"stnid\" value=\"\" class=\"text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all\"></fieldset></form>");

        $( "#printLabelDialog" ).dialog( "open" );

    });
});
```

I am trying to get the value of the textbox with id `ipAddr` using the line `var ip = $("#ipAddr").val();` which is returning null.

Comment: Do you have Firebug? What do you get if you add a line console.log($("#ipAddr"));?

Comment: I am getting the correct object if I log it but I am not able to get it in a variable

Comment: OK. Weird. Could it be the variable ip getting lost, is 'stnid' ok? What if you try ipAddr : $("#ipAddr").val(),

Comment: `$("#ipAddr").val();` gets the correct value, but the `stnid` is also getting null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I set the value of `#printLabelDialog` to the gif image using `$( this ).html(ajax_load);` before I get the value of the textbox in that div and hence I was getting the error.

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var e = document.getElementById("ipAddr");
var ip = e.value;
```

This should get the value of ipAddr, if, of course, there is already something inside of ipAddr. otherwise this will still return null.

Comment: I think the line `var ip = $("#ipAddr").val();` does the same. Anyways tried that and it did not work.

Comment: Then your input tag is empty, this means you're supposed to make a trigger that only gets the value you're trying to get the moment it at least has something inside. Try making a button and a $().click function before triggering the function in which you need the value. This way you can make sure it has been filled.

Comment: I entered value inside the textbox before clicking and I am able to get the value in log